# How to have multiple filters working in tandem? HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a filter for my place of work's website, it will allow the user to select some categories and then relevant shoes will be displayed below the filter, the current iteration can be seen in the image below.
[image: Current attempt]
However I am having some issues with getting the logic right, for example only the gender filters work properly (like radio buttons) and when 'Show All' is selected they are the only ones to become unactive, the other two filters currently do not act like this and will ignore that I clicked 'Show All' but it will still show all products whilst the currently active filters retain the appearance of being active.

I want the 'Style' and 'Colour' filters to allow for multiple active options at once- so that the user could look for both trainers and boots that are available in black, red and green all at once, but currently, whilst they may look like they are still active only the most recently clicked option is actually active meaning shoes that should qualify are being excluded from the user's view.

I am the only one working here with any experience in these languages and I wouldn't say I'm anything more than Junior-level and would appreciate the help in amending the issues in my code and logic.

The filter's HTML:

```
<!-- Filter 1 (gender filter - working) -->
<div class="filterbar">
    <button class="filter_btn-1 active" onclick="filterSelection('all')" title="Show All: Reset Your Search">
        Show all
    </button> 

    <br>

    <span> Gender: </span>
    <br>
    <button class="filter_btn-1" onclick="filterSelection('boy')" title="View Boy's Footwear"> 
        Boys 
    </button> 
    <button class="filter_btn-1" onclick="filterSelection('girl')" title="View Girl's Footwear"> 
        Girls 
    </button>
</div>

<!-- Filter 2 (style filter, not working (Filter 3 (colours) is basically identical to this but with different values)) -->
<div class="filterbar">
    <span> Style: </span>
    <br>
    <button class="filter_btn-2" onclick="filterSelection('school')" title="View School Footwear"> 
        School 
    </button> 
    <button class="filter_btn-2" onclick="filterSelection('trainer')" title="View Trainers"> 
        Trainers
    </button>
    <button class="filter_btn-2" onclick="filterSelection('out_school')" title="View Out-Of-School Footwear"> 
        Casual
    </button> 
</div>
```

The HTML for where the actual products will be visible:

```
<!-- Where the products will be visible after filtering -->
<div class="ob_scrollmenu" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="ob_filter ob_show boy" title="Control Shoe">
            <a href="#">
                <img style="width: 150px; font-size: 20px;" src="#.jpg" alt="Boys Control Shoe">
                <br>
            </a>
            RRP £45
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="ob_filter ob_show boy school black" title="Boy's Black School Shoe">
            <a href="#">
                <img style="width: 150px; font-size: 20px;" src="#.jpg" alt="Boy's Black School Shoe">
                <br>
            </a>
            RRP £45
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="ob_filter ob_show boy trainer white" title="Boy's White Trainer">
            <a href="#">
                <img style="width: 150px; font-size: 20px;" src="#.jpg" alt="Boy's White Trainer"> 
                <br>
            </a>
            RRP £45
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript (I have no real experience with this language other than a collection of snippets I commonly use)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // All products should be visible upon clicking "Show All" button
    // Temporarily the default option
    filterSelection("all")

    // When a filter is selected it decides which products to hide and show
    function filterSelection(c) {
     var x, i;
     x = document.getElementsByClassName("ob_filter");
     if (c == "all") c = "";
     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       RemoveClass(x[i], "ob_show");
       if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) AddClass(x[i], "ob_show");
     }
    }

    // SUB-ROUTINE | If product wasn't in the selected category before but now is, set to visible
    function AddClass(element, name) {
     var i, arr1, arr2;
     arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
     arr2 = name.split(" ");
     for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
       if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
     }
    }

    // SUB-ROUTINE | If product was in the selected category but now isn't, set to hidden
    function RemoveClass(element, name) {
     var i, arr1, arr2;
     arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
     arr2 = name.split(" ");
     for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
       while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
         arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
       }
     }
     element.className = arr1.join(" ");
    }

    // Add active class to the current button (highlights the active filter)
    var btns1 = document.getElementsByClassName("filter_btn-1");
    var btns2 = document.getElementsByClassName("filter_btn-2");

    for (var i = 0; i < btns1.length; i++) {
        btns1[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            var current1 = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            current1[0].className = current1[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            this.className += " active";
        });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < btns2.length; i++) {
        btns2[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
            var current2 = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            this.className = current2[0].className.replace(" active", ""); 
            window.alert("Made Unactive");
        } else { 
            var current2 = document.getElementsByClassName(" active");
            this.className += " active";
            window.alert("Made Active");
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:** JSFiddle link to the entirety of this problem can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/o40nqdth/

Comment: btw. just use the `classList` Api of DOM nodes, you do not have to code all that gain…

Comment: That's something I know exists but have no experience with using, I was planning on getting the logic to work first and then once I'm happy with it to then try shortening it.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post your whole code so I could run it? Maybe in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I just tried making one, I put everything in the correct section, but it didn't work for me. So I've just placed it all in the HTML section, here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/o40nqdth/ I'll also add an edit to my question with the link too.